# What is the VC-dimension of regular convex k-gons in the plane?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, machine-learning

Recall the relevant definitions:

Let $H$ be a family of sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The intersection of $H$ with a point set $C$ is defined as $H\cap C = \{h\cap C\mid h\in H\}$. The VC-dimension of $H$ (denoted by $VC(H)$) is the maximum $n$ such that there exists a set $C$ of $n$ points with $|H\cap C| = 2^n$.

Now let $k > 2$ and consider the family $H_k$ of all regular convex $k$-gons in the plane.

My question is: what is the VC-dimension of $H_k$?

If we restrict ourselves to homothets or translates of a convex set in the plane then the VC-dimension is at most $3$ [1]. But here I want to allow rotations, so this result doesn't apply (at not least directly).

Ben-David and Lindenbaum [2] give results which bound the VC-dimension of the range space consisting of all sets similar to a given semi-algebraic set in terms of the dimension and degree of this set. Their results imply in particular that $VC(H_k)=O(\log k)$. But I'm unable to construct a matching lower bound, and I'm not even sure there isn't a fixed upper bound which doesn't depend on $k$. Does this (or special cases) appear anywhere in the literature? (or lecture notes, or whatever)

[1]*Naszódi, Márton; Taschuk, Steven*, [**On the transversal number and VC-dimension of families of positive homothets of a convex body**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2009.07.030), Discrete Math. 310, No. 1, 77-82 (2010). [ZBL1192.52006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1192.52006).

[2]*Ben-David, Shai; Lindenbaum, Michael*, [**Localization vs. identification of semi-algebraic sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1007447530834), Mach. Learn. 32, No. 3, 207-224 (1998). [ZBL0912.68167](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0912.68167).

Comment: This posting, [The VC dimension of convex d-gons](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821302/237), claims that "The VC dimension of convex -gons is 2+1."

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thanks! However this is for general convex d-gons, while I'm interested in *regular* convex d-gons (the situation is surely different, as a VC-dimension of $2d+1$ would be incompatible with the $O(\log d)$ upper bound I mention in the question).